# NSInvalidArgumentException using va_start & va_end

Tags: objective-c

Including a C file in Objective-C App with a method that uses:

```
va_start(args, format);
vsnprintf(msg, sizeof(msg), format, args);
va_end(args);
```

Compiles but generates

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

at

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

If i don't

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

Then I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_va_end", referenced from:
  :
  "_va_start", referenced from:
  :
```

So it looks like the

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

Is causing the exception !?!?!?!

Using XCode 4.5.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Including the header file is not causing the exception, something you're doing causes the exception. The text of your exception does not directly implicate using variadic functions nor vsnprintf, so perhaps you should take a look at how you're using the NSURL class. Since you've got Xcode, make use of its debugger.

Comment: Yep, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  It LOOKED like the begining of the app, but of course it was during initialisation !